# Unexpected value of __callee__ when including a module – is this a Ruby bug?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, metaprogramming, alias-method

When invoked via a method created by `alias_method`, `__callee__` ignores the name of the old method (here `xxx`) and returns the name of the new method, as below:

```
class Foo
  def xxx() __callee__ end
  alias_method :foo, :xxx
end

Foo.new.foo # => :foo
```

This behavior holds even when `xxx` is inherited from a superclass:

```
class Sup
  def xxx() __callee__ end
end

class Bar < Sup
  alias_method :bar, :xxx
end

Bar.new.bar # => :bar
```

Given both of the above, I would expect that the same behavior would hold when `xxx` is included via a module. However, that is not the case:

```
module Mod
  def xxx() __callee__ end
end

class Baz
  include Mod
  alias_method :baz, :xxx
end

Baz.new.baz # => :xxx
```

I expect the return value to be `:baz`, not `:xxx`.

---

The above code was executed using Ruby 2.3.1p112. Is this a bug in the implementation of `__callee__`? Or maybe of `alias_method`? And if not, can anyone explain why module inclusion behaves differently?

---

**UPDATE 1**

I've [posted this to the Ruby bug tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12058) to try to stir up an answer.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Apparently, I'm [not the only one](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11964) to be surprised by this issue. I wonder whether [Revision 50728](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/50728) (which was meant to solve [Bug 11046: *`__callee__` returns incorrect method name in orphan proc*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11046)) might be related.

Comment: Very interesting, definitely changed between 2.2 and 2.3. Same for `__method__`.

Comment: @NilsLandt Can you give an example of the behavior for `__method__`? I replaced `__callee__` with `__method__` and got `xxx` returned for all 3 cases. Is it different in Ruby 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug, and it was closed 3 days ago [with this note](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12058#note-4):

> Seems fixed by [r56592](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/56592).

Answer (score 2):

You can see the difference between `__callee__` and `__method__` in Ruby's Kernel module.

The difference is the calls `prev_frame_callee()` and `prev_frame_func()`, respectively. I found these function definitions at http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/eval.c

In short, Foo and Bar are immediately calling the aliased methods foo and bar (which are names for xxx), while Baz has to find Mod and call xxx from Mod. `__method__` looks for the original called method's id, while `__callee__` looks for the closest called method's id to the `__callee__` call. This is better seen in `eval.c` at lines 848 to 906: look for the difference in the two methods on the return calls similar to `<something> -> called_id` vs `<something> -> def->original_id`.

Also, if you look at the Kernel from version 1.9.3, you will see that the two methods originally were the same. So, at some point, there was a purposeful change between the two.